# How can I improve the launch time react native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, performance

I've already published an app for IOS and Android.

But the app makes launch time around 5 seconds.

I detect it to make around 5 seconds to load the first screen in Routes

The app.tsx code below:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import configureStore from './Store';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Routes from './configs/Routes';
import {navigationRef} from './services/NavigationService';
import {LocalizationProvider} from './locales/Translation';
import ModalContainer from './modules/ModalGlobal/containers/ModalContainer';
import NetInfoContainer from './containers/NetInfoContainer';
import {
  listenNotificationForeground,
  requestUserPermission,
} from './services/NotificationService';
import axios from 'axios';
import {removeCurrentSession} from './modules/Setting/service/SettingService';
import {UNAUTHORIZED} from './configs/Constants';

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const {status} = error.response;
    if (status === UNAUTHORIZED) {
      removeCurrentSession();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
); // User for HTTP code difirrent 200 from axios

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let listenBackground: any;
    async function _notificationHandle() {
      await requestUserPermission();
      listenBackground = listenNotificationForeground();
    }
    _notificationHandle();
    return listenBackground;
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={configureStore().store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={configureStore().persistor}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <LocalizationProvider>     // Locale language
            <NetInfoContainer />     // Use to show lost connection
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
              <Routes />
            </NavigationContainer>
            <ModalContainer />      // Define global modal to use many routes
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Could I improve anything in this code? Or any way to improve launch time?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope my answer helped

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. I'm working with another feature so I haven't tried it. I reply the final result. Thanks

Comment: If it does help, please mark as accepted, and upvote! It helps a lot! :)

Comment: @JeafGilbert I got the issue. The redux-persist will take 5 seconds as default to load persist data. So I changed the default init time to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

for android you can eliminate blank screen at the beginning of the project by enabling [hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes) on app/build.gradle. Hermes convert js code to java code. If you defector your release apk, you can see only java file after enabling hermes and there is a change to reduce the size of your application. the full instruction and documentation see [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes)

Comment: Thanks. I've already enabled hermes to project. But the launch time not reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-screens](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens) to optimize the memory usage and performance of your app, use it as follow (After installing it with `yarn add react-native-screens`):

Your `android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java` need to look like this:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
}
```

On your entry file (Mostly App.js), add the following:

```js
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';

enableScreens(false);
```

More about it here: [Optimize memory usage and performance using react-native-screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/react-native-screens/)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. This module doesn't help improve time loading. I also add [hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes)  to this project. But still not improve anything :(((

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a splash-screen (if you don't have one) because there will always be a blank screen at the start of 1 second while react-native loads its dependencies. Setting up a splash screen will make this unnoticeable.

i use react-native-splash-screen

Comment: Thanks. I've already added splash screen.